# How to splitting different special characters in Java with using if contains?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, split, contains

I have “-“ characters in my strings as below.
I am using if contains “-“ and splitting correctly. But some string values are also “-“ characters in different indexes.
I tried to use 2nd if contains “.-“ cannot solve the issue as well.
So have can I get correct outputs without “-“ characters perfectly?

13-adana-demirspor -> has 2 “-“ characters.

15-y.-malatyaspor -> has “-“ characters too.

1st and 2nd strings makes problem for splitting.

And others has only one “-“ character and no issue.

My Code is:

```
final String [] URL  = {
            "13-adana-demirspor",
            "14-fenerbahce",
            "15-y.-malatyaspor",
            "16-trabzonspor",
            "17-sivasspor",
            "18-konyaspor",
            "19-giresunspor",        
            "20-galatasaray"
          };

        for(int i=0; i<URL.length; i++)

        String team;

    if (URL[i].contains("-")) {
        String[] divide = URL[i].split("-");
        team = divide[1];
        System.out.println("     " + team.toUpperCase());

    } else if (URL[i].contains(".-")){
        String[] divide = URL[i].split(".-");
        team = divide[2];
        System.out.println("     " + team.toUpperCase());

    }else {
        team = null;
    }
```

My Output is:

ADANA ** missing second word

FENERBAHCE

Y. ** missing second word

TRABZONSPOR

SIVASSPOR

KONYASPOR

GIRESUNSPOR

GALATASARAY

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if `URL[i].contains(".-")` is true, `URL[i].contains("-")` is also always true, thus `} else if (URL[i].contains(".-")){` is never executed. Put that statement above the first if statement

Comment: I changed like: 1st is if (URL[i].contains(".-")) and 2nd is else if (URL[i].contains("-")  but same result. Can you update my code for me to clarify?

Comment: You could use the overloaded method [`split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)) with a limit of `2`. Then there is no need for the additional `if` checks.

Comment: Actually I need to find word after the last "-" characters from left or first character from the right condition.  So (13-adana-demirspor can ignore). Like 15-y.-malatyaspor - will be MALATYASPOR only is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you just want to split on the first occurence. for this you can use the second parameter of `split` and set that to 2. So like

```
if (URL[i].contains("-")) {
    String[] divide = URL[i].split("-", 2);
    team = divide[1];
    System.out.println("     " + team.toUpperCase());
} else {
    team = null;
}
```

to get the last part instead you could do

```
if (URL[i].contains("-")) {
    String[] divide = URL[i].split("-");
    team = divide[divide.length - 1];
    System.out.println("     " + team.toUpperCase());
} else {
    team = null;
}
```

Comment: Ivo Beckers, it's ok now but I got F.-KARAGUMRUK and Y.-MALATYASPOR with "-"s now. How we can split after last "-"? Because I have a long url and only identify last "-" easily. (meaning right sided last one in front of  the word)

Comment: @Noo730 see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much. I have both alternatives right now.